# Calculation of failure rate and date time manipulation in R

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr, reshape2

I have a sample dataframe that I am working with

```
Datetime <- c("2015-09-29 08:22:00", "2015-09-29 09:45:00", "2015-09-29 09:53:00", "2015-09-29 10:22:00", "2015-09-29 10:42:00",
                  "2015-09-29 11:31:00", "2015-09-29 11:47:00", "2015-09-29 12:45:00", "2015-09-29 13:11:00", "2015-09-29 13:44:00",
                  "2015-09-29 15:24:00", "2015-09-29 16:28:00", "2015-09-29 20:22:00", "2015-09-29 21:38:00", "2015-09-29 23:34:00")
Measurement <- c("Length","Length","Width","Height","Width","Height","Length","Width","Width","Height","Width","Length",
                     "Length","Height","Height")
PASSFAIL <- c("PASS","PASS","FAIL","PASS","PASS","FAIL_AVG_HIGH","FAIL#Pts","FAIL","FAIL_AVG_LOW","FAIL","PASS","PASS","FAIL#RNG#HIGH","PASS","FAIL")

df1 <- data.frame(Datetime,Measurement,PASSFAIL)
```

df1

```
              Datetime Measurement      PASSFAIL
1  2015-09-29 08:22:00      Length          PASS
2  2015-09-29 09:45:00      Length          PASS
3  2015-09-29 09:53:00       Width          FAIL
4  2015-09-29 10:22:00      Height          PASS
5  2015-09-29 10:42:00       Width          PASS
6  2015-09-29 11:31:00      Height FAIL_AVG_HIGH
7  2015-09-29 11:47:00      Length      FAIL#Pts
8  2015-09-29 12:45:00       Width          FAIL
9  2015-09-29 13:11:00       Width  FAIL_AVG_LOW
10 2015-09-29 13:44:00      Height          FAIL
11 2015-09-29 15:24:00       Width          PASS
12 2015-09-29 16:28:00      Length          PASS
13 2015-09-29 20:22:00      Length FAIL#RNG#HIGH
14 2015-09-29 21:38:00      Height          PASS
15 2015-09-29 23:34:00      Height          FAIL
```

I am working on an interesting problem to find the failure rate for each measurement at 12AM-12PM & 12PM-12AM (next day) in a day.

Note: In df1, anything that has FAIL in PASSFAIL column is considered a failure.

```
Fail Rate = (Number of Fails)/(Number of Fails + Number of Pass)
```

My desired output is something like this

```
                Datetime FailRate_length Total_length FailRate_Width Total_Width FailRate_Height Total_Height
1 2015-09-29 00:00:00 AM            0.33            3           0.50           2            0.50            2
2 2015-09-29 12:00:00 PM            0.50            2           0.66           3            0.66            3
```

I am trying to use dplyr and data.table packages to solve this but I am just not knowing how to divide the time intervals in df1 to obtain df2 which has  2 values -> 12AM (The first 7 observations of df1) & 12PM (The next 8 observations in df1). Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using data.table...

```
library(data.table)

# thanks to @DavidArenburg for suggesting this approach:

df1[, `:=`( 
  d        = as.IDate(Datetime), 
  antepost = c("am","pm")[1+(hour(Datetime) >= 12)] ) 
]

res <- setDT(df1)[ , .( 
  failrate    = sum(PASSFAIL != "PASS")/.N,
  N           = .N
), by = .(d, antepost, Measurement)]
```

which gives

```
            d antepost Measurement  failrate N
1: 2015-09-29       am      Length 0.3333333 3
2: 2015-09-29       am       Width 0.5000000 2
3: 2015-09-29       am      Height 0.5000000 2
4: 2015-09-29       pm       Width 0.6666667 3
5: 2015-09-29       pm      Height 0.6666667 3
6: 2015-09-29       pm      Length 0.5000000 2
```

The syntax is `DT[i,j,by]` where `by` is for grouping variables; and `j` is for working with columns. `:=` within `j` creates new columns.

To reshape to the OP's desired output...

```
dcast(res, d + antepost ~ Measurement, value.var = c("failrate", "N"))
```

which gives

```
            d antepost failrate_Height failrate_Length failrate_Width N_Height N_Length N_Width
1: 2015-09-29       am       0.5000000       0.3333333      0.5000000        2        3       2
2: 2015-09-29       pm       0.6666667       0.5000000      0.6666667        3        2       3
```

---

Thanks to @Arun, here is a way to do it all in one step:

```
dcast(setDT(df1), 
  as.IDate(Datetime) + c("am","pm")[1+(hour(Datetime) >= 12)] ~ Measurement, 
  value.var = "PASSFAIL", 
  fun.agg = list(function(x) sum(x != "PASS")/length(x), length)
)
```

which gives

```
     Datetime Datetime_1 PASSFAIL_function_Height PASSFAIL_function_Length PASSFAIL_function_Width PASSFAIL_length_Height PASSFAIL_length_Length PASSFAIL_length_Width
1: 2015-09-29         am                0.5000000                0.3333333               0.5000000                      2                      3                     2
2: 2015-09-29         pm                0.6666667                0.5000000               0.6666667                      3                      2                     3
```

The column names are auto-generated from the root variables in the `~` part and the first word of each function definition.

Comment: I got the first part of the script working. It looks wonderful. But the dcast line is throwing an error saying "Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : subscript out of bounds" . Could you please check that?

Comment: Very nice, though it will be probably more efficient to create `d` and `antepost` before the grouping operations if the data set is very big, as `as.IDate` and `as.POSIXlt` aren't very efficient.

Comment: @Sharath It's possible that you don't have the latest version of the data.table package...? It is working on my end. Maybe start a new R session just to test this code, and compare `sessionInfo()` against the latest version of data.table on CRAN (currently 1.9.6)

Comment: @Frank, Perfect. I just updated the data.table package. This is a fantastic solution. I just applied it to my bigger dataset and it works like charm. Thank you so much Frank.

Comment: @Sharath Ok cool. Hope you have a look at the section added at the end. I agree with David that it probably makes sense to add the grouping vars to your original data set.

Comment: Yes. I too agree with David it makes a lot of sense to add the grouping vars to df1.

Comment: You can do it directly as well: `dcast(setDT(df1), as.IDate(Datetime) + c("am","pm")[1+(hour(Datetime) >= 12)] ~ Measurement, value.var = "PASSFAIL", fun.agg=list(function(x) sum(x != "PASS")/length(x), length))` - `dcast.data.table` access multiple functions in `fun.aggregate` as well.

Comment: @Arun Thanks, I'll add that. Are there plans to allow for customization of colnames in `dcast` results? It would be nice if something like `.(d=as.IDate(Datetime)) + .(antepost = c("am","pm")[1+(hour(Datetime) >= 12)]) ~ Measurement` worked in a formula, and maybe something else (not sure what) for the combinatorial cases introduced by multiple `fun.agg` and `value.var`.

Answer (score 3):

**A dplyr + tidyr equivalent** (with slightly different binning, although the one above was elegant):

```
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>%
  mutate(
    half_day = 
      Datetime %>%
      as.POSIXct(tz = "UTC") %>%
      round_any(60*60*12, f = floor) ) %>%
  group_by(half_day, Measurement) %>%
  summarize(Total = n(),
         FailRate = sum(PASSFAIL != "PASS")/Total) %>%
  gather(variable, value, FailRate, Total) %>%
  unite(variable_new, variable, Measurement, sep = "_") %>%
  spread(variable_new, value)
```

The `gather`, `unite`, `spread` sequence is the tidyr equivalent of `dcast`. Note that

> half day * (12 hour/half day) * (60 min / hour) * (60 seconds/min) = 60*60*12 seconds